# applying impulse to SKShapeNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    var player = SKShapeNode()
    let ballRadius: CGFloat = 20

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        view.scene?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5,y : 0.5)
        player = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: ballRadius)
        player.name = "player"
        player.fillColor = .green
        player.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        player.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true

        self.addChild(player)

        player.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 10))
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        // Called before each frame is rendered
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add an impulse to player but I just can't figure it out, please be very specific for I am a beginner. I think it has to do with the skshapenode not being a volume based object but I am not sure

Comment: You didn't create a physics body actually. It is nil at the time when you apply impulse to it, but it doesn't crash due to optional chaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track! All you need to do is add a physics body to your player to make it move.

```
player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 30) 
    // the 30 in this case is an example. You can just change it to whatever you want
```